# What is the easiest way of creating a value of a large F# record?

Tags: f#

I'm learning F# and I want to know if I'm approaching it the right way. I created a record type that contain 6 labels but it can easily grow to 10+ labels. **How should I design its constructor?** Since record values are immutable, I think I should create in one go. Each parameter in the constructor map to a label when constructing the value. However, this just feels wrong.

For example:

```
module Deal =
    open System

    type T = {
        Title : string;
        Description: string;
        NumberOfVotes: int;
        NumberOfComments: int;
        DateCreated: DateTime;
        ImageUrl: string;
    }


    let Create (title:string) (desc:string) (numberOfVotes:int) (numberOfComments:int) (dateCreated: DateTime) (imageUrl:string) =
        {
                Title = title;
                Description = desc;
                NumberOfVotes = numberOfVotes;
                NumberOfComments = numberOfComments;
                DateCreated = dateCreated;
                ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
```

I don't think the constructor scales nicely as more labels are added to the record.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why do you need a constructor? Can't you just use the normal record construction syntax?

Comment: Sooner or later, I'm going to introduce restrictions in the constructor like how it's done in this tutorial (https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-representing-states/)  which is why I need a constructor

Comment: If you are thinking about constructors, why not just create a class instead of a record. You can also put validation logic in there, you can have multiple constructors, named parameters, and optional parameters.

Comment: I guess I could use a class instead of a record. I used a record because that's what the tutorial that I mentioned previously used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *F# for fun and profit* example the email address being stored is a string and it's in a wrapper type (a discriminated union is used). You don't seem to have a wrapper type. This is how I would adapt the example to your case:

```
open System

type Deal =
    { Title : string; Description: string; NumberOfVotes: int
      NumberOfComments: int; DateCreated: DateTime; ImageUrl: string }

module Deal = 
    type ValidDeal =
        private ValidDeal of Deal // Note the `private` on the case constructor

    let isValid deal = true // Add implementation

    let create deal =
        if isValid deal then Some (ValidDeal deal)
        else None

    let (|ValidDeal|) (ValidDeal deal) = deal // This is an active pattern

open Deal
let f (ValidDeal d) = d // Use the active pattern to access the Deal itself.

let g d = ValidDeal d // Compile error. The ValidDeal union case constructor is private
```

Note that the `ValidDeal` union case constructor is private to the `Deal` module, which also contains the `isValid` function. So this module has complete control over over the validation of deals. Any code outside of this module must use `Deal.create` to create a valid deal and if any function receives a `ValidDeal` there is something of a compile time guarantee of validity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I called the Deal.create(), it returns a ValidDeal but I wasn't able to access its values (ie: Title, Description, etc). Do you know how your code can be refactored so that I can access those values?

Comment: Nevermind.. I think I figured it out by unwrapping ValidDeal to expose Title, Description, etc. I'm using this tutorial as my guide: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/

Answer (score 4):

Record construction generally does not scale very well: You will need to add the additional fields for every construction expression. If you can assign sensible default values to your additional fields, a constructor with optional arguments may help.

```
open System
type Deal =
    { Title : string; Description: string; NumberOfVotes: int
      NumberOfComments: int; DateCreated: DateTime; ImageUrl: string } with
    static member Create
        (   ?title : string, 
            ?desc : string, 
            ?numberOfVotes : int, 
            ?numberOfComments : int, 
            ?dateCreated: DateTime,
            ?imageUrl : string ) =
            {   Title = defaultArg title "No title"
                Description = defaultArg desc "No description"
                NumberOfVotes = defaultArg numberOfVotes 0
                NumberOfComments = defaultArg numberOfComments 0
                DateCreated = defaultArg dateCreated DateTime.Now
                ImageUrl = defaultArg imageUrl "Default.jpg" }
```

While being even more boilerplate, additional fields can be introduced without impacting constructor call sites. There are two ways to supply specific arguments, either named arguments or F#'s copy-and-update record expressions.

```
Deal.Create(title = "My Deal")  // named argument
{ Deal.Create() with NumberOfVotes = 42 }   // copy-and-update
```